# PHP SimpleXML - Multiple children with same name

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, parent-child

I am currently generating an xml file with the following php code. It takes form inputs and puts them into an xml file.

I am wanting to have multiple children with the same name. Eg:

```html
<person>
  <address>
    <street>streetname</street>
    <streetnumber>streetnumber</streetnumber>
  </address>
  <address>
    <street>streetname</street>
    <streetnumber>streetnumber</streetnumber>
  </address>
</person>
```

My code to generate the xml follows this structure;

```html
//Add first address - working

$xml->person = "";
$xml->person->address = "";

$xml->person->address->addChild('streetname', $_POST['streetname1']);
$xml->person->address->addChild('streetnumber', $_POST['streetnumber1']);


//Attempt to add second address, doesn't work

$xml->person->address = "";

$xml->person->address->addChild('streetname', $_POST['streetname2']);
$xml->person->address->addChild('streetnumber', $_POST['streetnumber2']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's much easier and less verbose to use variables when building your XML document. Then you can add multiple `<address>` elements to your `<person>` element like this...

```
$person = $xml->addChild('person');

$address1 = $person->addChild('address');
$address1->addChild('streetname', $_POST['streetname1']);
$address1->addChild('streetnumber', $_POST['streetnumber1']);

$address2 = $person->addChild('address');
$address2->addChild('streetname', $_POST['streetname2']);
$address2->addChild('streetnumber', $_POST['streetnumber2']);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked just as I wanted it to. Very appreciative.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help.